# Max geometric body inside another one

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

If we take in consideration the dimensions of the Giza Great Pyramid, what would be the maximum size of an sphere put *inside* the building? How can I calculate same for an outer sphere on the pyramid vertices, at maximum size?

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF5rK.png]]

Answer (score 1):

Hint...The largest internal sphere has to touch the base at its centre and touch the lines of symmetry of the triangular faces. So if $r$ is the radius of the sphere and $h$ is the height of the pyramid, we have $$\cos  51.87=\frac{r}{h-r}$$ and you can solve this for $r$